# How can I install Ubuntu via USB?

Tags: system-installation, usb, 13.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 in my notebook from an USB flash drive but when I try to boot or install directly from the USB I got the following messages and the process stops.

```
No Caching mode page present
Assuming drive cache: write through
Attached SCSI disk
```

What is the problem and what can I do in this case?

Comment: What is the laptop you are working on?

Comment: It is from a local manufacturer

Comment: @Mr.Lee Since this same hardware worked with windows without problems I don't think its the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hei
I don't really have time and this is more a comment than a Answer but maybe it helps

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HQvbH0UlQU

Maybe they found a solution he seems to have the same problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1795280.html

Comment: I have create the usb stick as described and still the same thing.

Comment: Could you upload a Screenshot?

Comment: Since it is in the installatin screen I don't think I there is a way to take a screen shot, but I will try to take a pic of the screen.

Comment: The image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5v9RA2pT0-UMlhHWHYzTjQ5QW5rQUgzMWJ5Mk1PU29WUkNF/

Comment: Maybe something went wrong while making the bootable USB Stick?

Comment: Might be, but I have done it a couple of times and the same error occur. It shows a Ubuntu screen, I select Install or Test or check and the same error happens.

Comment: Also I have used this stick to generate a Windows 7 disk, intalled it on my notebook and it worked nicely some time ago.

Comment: Hmm that is very weird.. Are you sour your Hardware is supported?

Comment: I am not sure but I am also not using anything strange

Comment: You could try another os or a LTS Version of Ubuntu to see if they have the same problem..

Comment: looks like that it's what is left for me...